# What structure is preserved by pseudo-homeomorphisms of pseudo-Euclidean spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, real-analysis, gn.general-topology, mg.metric-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics

Let us recall that for integer numbers $t,s\ge 0$ the *[pseudo-Euclidean space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-Euclidean_space)* $\mathbb R^{t,s}$ is the vector space $\mathbb R^{t+s}$ endowed with the quadratic form $q_{t,s}:\mathbb R^{t+s}\to\mathbb R$ assigning to every vector $x=(x)_{i\in t+s}$ the real number $$q_{t,s}(x)=\sum_{i\in t}x_i^2-\sum_{j\in s}x_{t+j}^2.$$
The pseudo-Euclidean space $\mathbb R^{1,3}$, called the *[Minkowski spacetime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_space)*, plays an important role in the Einstein Relativity Theory.

For every $x\in\mathbb R^{t,s}$ and $\varepsilon>0$, let $$B_{t,s}(x,\varepsilon):=\{y\in\mathbb R^{t,s}:|q_{t,s}(x-y)|<\varepsilon^2\}$$be the *pseudo-ball* of radius $\varepsilon$ around $x$.

In the pseudo-Euclidean space $\mathbb R^{1,1}$ the pseudo-ball of radius one around zero is the set of points between the hyperbolas:

[image: Pseudoball of radius 1 around zero]

A function $f:\mathbb R^{t,s}\to \mathbb R^{t,s}$ is defined to be *pseudo-continuous* if $$\forall x\in\mathbb R^{t,s}\;\forall\varepsilon>0\;\exists \delta>0\;f[B_{t,s}(x,\delta)]\subseteq B_{t,s}(f(x),\varepsilon).$$

A function $f:\mathbb R^{t,s}\to \mathbb R^{t,s}$ is defined to be a *pseudo-homeomorphism* of the pseudo-Euclidean space $\mathbb R^{t,s}$ if $f$ is bijective and the functions $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are pseudo-continuous.

The following natural problems are motivated by the famous [Erlangen Program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlangen_program) of [Felix Klein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Felix_Klein).

**Problem 1.** Describe the structure of individual pseudo-homeomorphisms of the pseudo-Euclidean spaces $\mathbb R^{t,s}$ and the structure of the group of pseudo-homeomorphisms of $\mathbb R^{t,s}$ (at least in the simplest non-trivial case of the pseudo-Euclidean space $\mathbb R^{1,1}$).

**Problem 2.** What structure of the pseudo-Euclidean space $\mathbb R^{t,s}$ is preserved by pseudo-homeomorphisms (so that a bijective function $f:\mathbb R^{t,s}\to\mathbb R^{t,s}$ is a pseudo-homeomorphism if and only if it preserves this structure)?

**Remark.** The notion of pseudo-continuity is not topological: no topology on $\mathbb R^{t,s}$ exists in which the continuity of functions is equivalent to the pseudo-continuity. So, the hypothetical structure on $\mathbb R^{t,s}$ preserved by pseudo-homeomorphisms (which can be called the *pseudo-topology*) should be something else, different from a topology.

Comment: Is it not a topology ( but different from the standard one)?

Comment: If we define a topology $\tau$ is a standard way as the family of sets $U\subseteq\mathbb R^{1,1}$ such that for any $u\in U$ there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that $B(u,\varepsilon)\subseteq U$, then $\tau=\{\emptyset,\mathbb R^{1,1}\}$ is the antidiscrete topology and all functions will be continuous for this topology, which is not true for the pseudo-continuity.

Comment: Why are you interested in pseudocontinuous functions?

Comment: @DeaneYang Because pseudo-continuous functions on pseudo-Euclidean spaces are analogs of continuous functions on Euclidean spaces. And the pseudo-Euclidean space $\mathbb R^{1,3}$ is very important for understanding the structure of our physical space-time. And because the usual topology is inappropriate for describing  "pseudo-topological" properties of space-time, which are manifested in pseudo-continuous functions and pseudo-homeomorphisms.

Comment: Could you provide a reference or two where the importance of pseudocontinuous functions in general relativity is explained? A vector space without any quadratic form already has a natural topology, and, as far as I can tell, most work in general relativity uses it.

Comment: @DeaneYang No, I cannot provide any reference, unfortunately (because I am not a specialist in Relativity Theory). Nonetheless, if we look at pseudo-Euclidean spaces from a ``metric'' point of view forgetting about the linear structure, we will have only the quadratic form and this quadratic form induces a kind of continuity. Such an approach to the Euclidean spaces resulted in creation of Topology, so why cannot I use it once more asking these questions? Maybe it will lead to creation of pseudo-topology? Who know?

Comment: I'll comment only on "forgetting about the linear structure". This cannot be done, because a linear structure is needed to be able to define a quadratic form and therefore your own definitions. The linear structure is crucial to the study of Minkowski space.

Comment: @DeaneYang But when we study the topology of a Euclidean space we usually forget about the linear structure and operate only with the topology, which is generated by the metric (which is just the square root of the quadratic form). Indeed, a linear structure is used for defining the quadratic form, but when it is defined, we can ask about properties dependent only on this quadratic form or the properties defined with the help of this quadratic form, like the pseudo-continuity. This is a standard approach of studying a mathematical object taking into account only some selected structures.

Comment: I don’t see how you can study geometric properties of Euclidean space using only its topology. It’s topologically equivalent to many non-Euclidean spaces such as hyperbolic space.

Comment: @DeaneYang There are many very deep  books studying the Geometric Topology of Eulclidean spaces with and without the linear structure), see e.g. https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/davenema.pdf

Comment: @DeaneYang The pseudo-continuity in pseudo-Euclidean spaces is not equivalent to the continuity with respect to the standard product topology. This means that there is  some kind of a "pseudo-topological" structure behind the pseudo-continuity, different from the standard Euclidean topology, and I just want to understand the essence of this mysterious structure, which shows up in pseudocontinuity but maybe in some other properties, too.

Answer (score 2):

### Solution to problem 1 and 2 in the $s=t=1$ case

In the $(1,1)$ case, change the quadratic form to $(x,y)\mapsto xy$ instead of $(x,y)\mapsto x^2 - y^2$. This is merely a change of coordinates.

**Theorem**: A function $f:\mathbb R^{1,1}\to \mathbb R^{1,1}$ is "pseudocontinuous" if and only if:

$$f(x,y)\equiv(g(x),h(y)),$$
or
$$f(x,y)\equiv(h(y),g(x)),$$
for any pair of continuous functions $g,h:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$. In particular, the group of pseudo-automorphisms is the semidirect product $(\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb R)\times \operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb R))\rtimes C_2$, where $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb R)$ is the set of automorphisms of $\mathbb R$ as a topological space.

Why? I list the sequence of lemmas which one should prove:

**Lemma 1**: A "cross" (that is, the union of a line parallel to the $x$ axis with a line parallel to the $y$ axis) necessarily gets mapped to another cross by any pseudocontinuous function $f$.

**Lemma 2**: A horizontal line or vertical line gets mapped to a horizontal or vertical line by pseudocontinuous $f$.

**Lemma 3**: For fixed $x$, the function $y \mapsto f(x,y)$ is continuous. The same is true for $x \mapsto f(x,y)$ for fixed $y$.

**Lemma 4**: The function $f$ is continuous everywhere.

**Theorem**: The above statement.

Comment: I imagined exactly such an answer (that pseudo-homeomorphisms decompose into coordinate functions). It is interesting whether this has some implications for theoretical physics.

Comment: @TarasBanakh I suspect the $s=t=2$ case will have something to do with the entire analytic functions on $\mathbb C$. More broadly, I think pseudocontinuity might sometimes imply differentiability or analyticity.

Comment: @TarasBanakh If indeed pseudo-continuity implies differentiability some of the time, then this does look rather interesting. The idea of having some sort of pseudo-topology  seems interesting too.

Comment: @TarasBanakh I suppose this is an example of a Chu space, but Chu spaces are massively more general, and I'm not sure what that observation leads to: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chu_space